# Connecting Substrate to Cactus Business logic plugin

Tags: substrate-node-template

I'm working with cactus interoperability and now I need to implement a plugin for cactus using substrate based blockchain.

Comment: can anyone help me in doing so

Comment: Can you provide context as to what cactus is?

Comment: Our intern Lilly is writing her Bachelor thesis about Hyperledger(https://www.hyperledger.org/use/cactus) integration. I'll ping her!